# "where .. in" analogue elasticsearch with Java API

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, nosql

I am new to ElasticSearch.
I've a string field in my User class, representing UserStatus and I need to search for all users in specific status. 
In relational DBs it is exactly "where .. in".

I saw examples, using `termsQuery` in different combinations, but I didn't manage to make them work (the query returned nothing).

So, the question is: is there a link, showing the entire example or someone faced such an issue? 
Any help is pleased!

//The entity itself

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Builder
    @Document(indexName = "users", type = "user")
    public class User {

        @Id
        private String id;

        private String userStatus;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private Date dateCreated;
    }
```

//A spring service method

```
@Override
public List<User> findByParams(UserSearchRequest userSearchRequest) {

    TermsQueryBuilder termsQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders
            .termsQuery("userStatus", userSearchRequest.getUserStatuses());


    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(boolQuery().must(termsQueryBuilder))
            .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 100))
            .build();


    return Lists.newArrayList(userRepository.search(searchQuery));

}
```

//REST request object

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class UserSearchRequest {
    private List<String> userStatuses;
}
```

Comment: have you tried running a direct query to elasticsearch (a curl or some sort of web based ui) instead of through Java? usually that is what helps me

Comment: I agree with @sfat, try out with the direct elastic search query. The following is a query for retrieving values values based on specific condition.

Comment: Here is an example query {"query" : {"constant_score" : {"filter" : { "bool" : { "should" : [ { "term" : {"employee" : "foo"}}]}}}}}.                                        method -> post,                                                                                             url ->  http://localhost:9200/<indexname>/<type name>/_search .

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation  of Elasticsearch for ["Finding Multiple Exact Values"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html)

Basically, you need to wrap your terms searchin into a constant score query.

From Elasticsearch doc (to keep for posterity)

```
GET /my_store/products/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { 
                    "price" : [20, 30]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example says search the products which have the price either 20 or 30.

What you want is search all the users that have the `userStatus` either one of the values that you pass as `List`.

In terms of implementation you would need to change your `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` in something like this:

```
 SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(constantScoreQuery(termsQueryBuilder))
                .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 100))
                .build();
```